# Multiple class in Mixin with same function

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs4, mixins

I used mixins(EXT Js 4) in my project. I have following structure. Two classes named Class A and Class B with following function.

```
Ext.define('ClassA', {        
    classAFunction: function() {      
       alert("ClassAFunction in class A");        
    }        
});

Ext.define('ClassB', {        
    classBFunction: function() {      
       alert("ClassBFunction in class B");        
    },

    classAFunction: function() {      
       alert("ClassAFunction in class B");        
    }           

});
```

In my controller i used mixins to extend the capability of my controller as shown in following code.

```
Ext.define(Site_Controller', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

views: [
    'ui.Site_View'
],

mixins: {
   classA: 'ClassA',        
   classB: 'ClassB'

},

init: function() {
    this.control({
        'MainPanel button[action=save]':{
            click: this.CreateSite
        }
    });
},

CreateSite: function() {

  alert("HELLO");
  this.classAFunction;
  this.classBFunction;
}

});
```

I call createsite method of controller on the click of button which is present in view. so when createsite method called first i got "HELLO" and than classAFunction called and it gives me "ClassAFunction in class A". So it call classA function But i want to call ClassAFunction which is present in classB. So In extjs how can i achive this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the mixins and call the function directly

```
this.mixins.classB.classAFunction.call(this);
```